# Non-homeomorphic spaces that can have homeomorphic open cones.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, singularity-theory

Apparently such a space exists, and apparently Milnors solution to Hauptvermutung also explains this situation. I am learning about topologically stratified spaces, so it would be nice to know a reference of a situation when the link is not necessarily well defined.

There is a reference to this fact [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=xfkcBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA324&lpg=PA324&dq=non%20homeomorphic%20links%20whose%20cones%20are%20homeomorphic%20milnor&source=bl&ots=BfbzG6q_xF&sig=8C3TuPpG4FnzqNtpl3494AMZ4lo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwipzNmuwojPAhVS7WMKHRICDMgQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=non%20homeomorphic%20links%20whose%20cones%20are%20homeomorphic%20milnor&f=false) (which suggestions looking at Milnors "Two Complexes which are homeomorphic but combinatorially distinct"), but I can't readily understand this.

Maybe there exists a simpler description that someone knows about?